# Using date variables in SQL select and where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I use Oracle SQL Developer and want to define multiple dates and use them multiple times in select and where clauses. They will change as I run this throughout the year. They are 4 dates for quarters shown here, but it will not always be quarters and I will have about 10 dates.

I want the query to provide counts in 4 categories and conversions to the next stage. Stages: View, Attract, Order, Fulfill. They are dates obtained from 4 subqueries.

```
--this is the part I don't know how to do

Define date1 = '2017-01-01' 
Define date2 = '2017-03-31'
Define date3 = '2017-04-01'
Define date4 = '2017-06-30'

--I want to set dates here and call them out in the query below.

select count(case when f_view between date1 and date2 then 1 else null    end) c_view
,count(case when f_attract between date1 and date2 then 1 else null end) c_attract
,count(case when f_order between date1 and date2 then 1 else null end) c_order
,count(case when f_fulfill between date1 and date2 then 1 else null end) c_fulfill
--the prev 4 statements are my method of getting the count
--the next 3 are for the conversion rates (case going from view to attract, etc)
,count(case when f_view between date1 and date2 then 1 else null end) 
/ count(case when f_attract is not null then 1 else null end) conv_view
,count(case when f_attract between date1 and date2 then 1 else null end)     
/ count(case when f_order is not null then 1 else null end) conv_attract
,count(case when f_order between date1 and date2 then 1 else null end) 
/ count(case when f_fulfill is not null then 1 else null end) conv_order
--I would continue this for 4 other date ranges
from (select f_case
,f_view
from view_table
where seq = 1) view
--every case has a view, but not every case has the other 3 dates
left join (select f_case
,max(f_attract) over (partition by f_case) f_attract
from order_table) attract
on view.f_case = attract.f_case
left join (select f_case
,max(f_order) over (partition by f_case) f_order
from order_table
where order_type = 'order') order
on view.f_case = order.f_case
left join (select f_case
,max(f_fulfill) over (partition by f_case) f_fulfill
from fulfill_table) fulfill
on view.f_case = fulfill.f_case
where f_view between date1 and date4
or f_attract between date1 and date4
or f_order between date1 and date4
or f_fulfill between date1 and date4
```

I can put the dates into the query, but then I have to change them all every time I run it (and there's so many!).

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

This seems rather basic PL/SQL, but it looks something like this:

```
declare
    v_date1 date;
    v_date2 date;
    v_date3 date;
    v_date4 date;
    v_field_1 number;
    v_field_2 number;
begin
    v_date1 := '2017-01-01';
    v_date2 := '2017-03-31';
    v_date3 := '2017-04-01';
    v_date4 := '2017-06-30';

   select sum(case when field1 between v_date1 and v_date2 then 1 else 0    end) as c_field1_1
          sum(case when field2 between v_date1 and v_date2 then 1 else 0 end) c_field2_1
    into v_field1, v_field2
    from ?
    where field1 between v_date1 and v_date4 or
          field2 between v_date1 and v_date4;

    dbms_output.print_line(v_field1 || ' ' || v_field2);
end;
```

Note that your query doesn't specify a `FROM` clause.

Comment: He may mean there's no `FROM` clause.

Comment: "He" looks pretty much like a "she" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't "define" (and assign values to) variables like that. If you want them hard-coded as in your example, you can "define" them in a subquery (or a WITH clause, if you know what that is) and use a join:

```
select <whatever>
from   <your_table> t    --  you are missing the FROM clause in your sample code!
       join
       ( select date '2017-01-01' as date1,
                date '2017-03-31' as date2,
                date '2017-04-01' as date3,
                date '2017-06-30' as date4
         from   dual
       ) d
       on t.field1 between d.date1 and d.date2  -- why "date4" in your sample code??
       or t.field2 between d.date3 and d.date4
;
```

If, in fact, the requirement is simply to "do something" with data partitioned by calendar quarter, there are much simpler ways - you don't need any kind of variables. It would be best if you told us the ORIGINAL problem you are trying to solve, not YOUR WAY of attacking it (which doesn't seem too efficient, besides not being quite correct either).